# decorating a function while accessing the for loop variables within decorated function

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, decorator

Currently I have a bunch of functions that loop through images, makes some changes and then plots each image.

```
def second (images):
    for image in images:
        image = imread(image)
        image = image - 100
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()
```

Now I wanted to decorate these functions so that for there is another subplot for each image. A subplot with a normal image and a subplot with the transformed image.

However, I need to be able to access the `image` from the `images` iteration with the `second` function, and for each iteration use this `image` within the wrapper.

Is there a clean way to do this?
I found a sort of hackish way to do this:

```
def plt_decorate(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        images = args[0] 
        for image in images:
            im = imread(image)
            mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager() #this two lines
            mng.window.state('zoomed')          # are just to zoom plot
            plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(im)
            if args[1:]:
                print( func([image], args[1:], **kwargs)) #can't return as loop ends
            else:
                print( func([image], **kwargs))
    return func_wrapper



@plt_decorate
def second (images):
    for image in images:
        image = imread(image)
        image = image - 100
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

A decorator aims to tranform the input before it is passed to your function. So the way you should proceed is to loop through `images`, mutate it or cause some side effects and then pass `images` to the function.

In your case it would look something like this.

```
def plt_decorate(func):

    def func_wrapper(images):

        for image in images:
            im = imread(image)
            mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
            mng.window.state('zoomed')
            plt.subplot(122)
            plt.imshow(im)

        return func(images)

    return func_wrapper



@plt_decorate
def second (images):
    for image in images:
        image = imread(image)
        image = image - 100
        plt.subplot(121)
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing what I need.  The iterated images  from both functions need to be in sync with each other.

Comment: What do you mean by in sync? Did you try the above and it failed? If so, what is wrong with the output?